# Problema ao pesquisar e filtrar dados de data em objeto

Tags: python, json

Possuo as seguintes funções para pesquisar e ordenar um usuário por uma determinada data, porém, ao rodar essas funções em um objeto, o mesmo gera um erro `KeyError: 0` na função `listagemData`

```
#Criar padrão para pesquisa por data
def criarStrData():
    ano = input("Por favor, informe o ANO para a busca (ex.: 1905)\n")
    mes = input("Por favor, informe o MÊS para a busca (ex.: 4, 5, 12)\n")
    dia = input("Por favor, informe o DIA para a busca (ex.: 15, 2, 29)\n")
    #Dia, Mês e Ano
    mda = "{}/{}/{}".format(mes,dia,ano)
    return mda

#Usar padrão para buscar usuários e inserí-los em listagem
def listagemData(usuarios, mda):
    listagemDt = []
    for i in range(0, len(usuarios)):
        print(usuarios[i])
        if usuarios[i][3][0] == mda:
            listagemDt.append(usuarios[i])
    return listagemDt

#Filtrar a lista em ordem
def filtroDt(listagemDt):
    elementos = len(listagemDt) - 1
    ordenado = False
    while not ordenado:
        ordenado = True
        for i in range(elementos):
            if datetime.datetime.strptime(listagemDt[i][3][1], "%H:%M") > datetime.datetime.strptime(listagemDt[i + 1][3][1], "%H:%M"):
                listagemDt[i], listagemDt[i + 1] = listagemDt[i + 1], listagemDt[i]
                ordenado = False
    return listagemDt`
```

A utilização das funções ocorre da seguinte maneira:

```
listaDtF = filtroDt(listagemData(usuarios, criarStrData()))
if len(listaDtF) > 0:
    for i in range(0, len(listaDtF)):
        print(listaDtF[i])    
    else:
        print("Nenhum registro encontrado\n")
```

o Objeto verificado é o objeto usuários:

```
{
    "murilomelo": ["Murilo Henrique Gamb\u00f4a de Melo", "Super Administrador de Sistema", 4, ["06/04/2019", "10:13"]],
    "Marcelo": ["Marcelo Almeida", "Administrador", 4, ["06/04/2019", "10:29"]],
    "AdrianaNeves": ["Adriana Neves Castro", "secret\u00e1ria", 1, ["06/04/2019", "10:30"]]
}
```

Como posso corrigir o código para buscar e filtrar a exibição deste objeto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cara pelo que eu vi voce esta tentando iterar sobre dicionários como se ele fosse uma lista, em python não é possível acessar um dicionário pela sintaxe `foo[2]` por exemplo, a não ser que `2` seja a chave desse dicionário, o correto seria `foo["key"]`. peguei sua função `listagemData` e mudei o acesso aos valores do dicionário, ficou assim

```py
    def listagemData(usuarios, mda):
    listagemDt = []
    for chave, valor in usuarios.items():
        print(valor)
        if valor[3][0] == mda:
            listagemDt.append({chave: valor})
    return listagemDt
```

Comment: o Anderson me ajudou no chat, vou rodar aqui, se funcionar já marco como resposta, pq é isso mesmo